# Extracting content of textarea in an iframe using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, textarea

I have an iframe 'description_ifr' within which is a textarea with ID/name of 'description'. I'd like to use vanilla javascript to extract the contents of that textarea.

There are several sites, including pages here, that purport to provide solutions. I believe I've tried everything on offer but still no success.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('description_ifr');
alert(typeof(iframe));

var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
alert(typeof(doc));

obj = doc.getElementById('description');
alert(typeof(obj));

var description = JSON.stringify(obj.value);
alert(description);
```

Results from the above are:
object
object
object
then a error: TypeError: obj is null

Comment: `typeof null` is `object` so I guess there is no `#description` element in that document when you run this code, you can use the `iframe.onload` callback to wait for the `iframe`'s contents to load.

Comment: If I understand iframe.onload correctly, then it will trigger some javascript function once the iframe has loaded. In otherwords, if the textarea comes preloaded with content then this will/might work. However, my textarea is initially blank – the user types something in and this is what I want picked up with an onsubmit handler.

Comment: Solved. It appears the normal iframe–javascript functionality is disrupted by the use of the tinymce editor (which internally produces the iframe). The solution is to use:
var description = tinymce.EditorManager.get('description').getContent();